# Copy arbitrary image formats (raster and vector) to clipboard with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am having troubles copying arbitrary data types with PyQt5 and then pasting the content into another software.

Specifically I want to copy either raster-graphics (png, jpeg etc..) OR vector-graphics (svg, eps, pdf) from a PyQt5 application and then paste it in some other application (document or image editing software).

The code I use to copy raster images works perfectly fine and allows me to copy/paste images into arbitrary software.

- however, it copies a rasterized version of the image even if the format is a vektor-graphics type

It looks somewhat like this:

```py
import io
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage

...

with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
    self.savefig(buffer, format="png")
    cb = QApplication.clipboard()            
    cb.setImage(QImage.fromData(buffer.getvalue()))
```

Now, to be able to copy vector graphics, I extended the above script to handle arbitrary mimetypes:

```py
import io
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

...

with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
    self.savefig(buffer, format="svg")
    data = QMimeData()
    data.setData("image/svg+xml", buffer.getvalue())

    cb = QApplication.clipboard()            
    cb.clear(mode=cb.Clipboard)
    cb.setMimeData(data, mode=cb.Clipboard)
```

Now this still works fine (both raster and vektor) if I paste the copied data into a software like Inkscape, but to some unknown reason I can no longer paste the data (no matter if its vektor or raster images) in other programs like LibreOffice Writer, MarkTex, paint etc. )

Is there something I am missing in my code so that the copied data is recognized properly by all apps?

#### Update

---

Here is a minimal working example to show the behavior:

My question comes down to:
Why do the `copy png/svg with setData` buttons not work as expected?
Somehow images cannot be pasted into other apps (except for Inkscape).

```py
import io

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


@pyqtSlot()
def button_pressed_png_set_image():
    f, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title("png copied with setImage")
    ax.plot([1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 8], "b")

    with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
        f.savefig(buffer, format="png")
        cb = QApplication.clipboard()
        cb.setImage(QImage.fromData(buffer.getvalue()))
    print("copied png to clipboard!")
    plt.close(f)

@pyqtSlot()
def button_pressed_svg_set_image():
    f, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title("svg copied with setImage")
    ax.plot([1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 8], "r")

    with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
        f.savefig(buffer, format="svg")
        cb = QApplication.clipboard()
        cb.setImage(QImage.fromData(buffer.getvalue()))
    print("copied svg to clipboard!")
    plt.close(f)


@pyqtSlot()
def button_pressed_svg_set_data():
    with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
        f, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.set_title("svg copied with setData")
        ax.plot([1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 8], "b--")

        f.savefig(buffer, format="svg")
        data = QMimeData()
        data.setData("image/svg+xml", buffer.getvalue())

        cb = QApplication.clipboard()
        cb.clear(mode=cb.Clipboard)
        cb.setMimeData(data, mode=cb.Clipboard)
    print("copied svg to clipboard!")
    plt.close(f)

@pyqtSlot()
def button_pressed_png_set_data():
    with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
        f, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.set_title("png copied with setData")
        ax.plot([1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 8], "r--")

        f.savefig(buffer, format="png")
        data = QMimeData()
        data.setData("image/png", buffer.getvalue())

        cb = QApplication.clipboard()
        cb.clear(mode=cb.Clipboard)
        cb.setMimeData(data, mode=cb.Clipboard)
        plt.close(f)
    print("copied png to clipboard!")
    plt.close(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("copy png with setImage")
    button.pressed.connect(button_pressed_png_set_image)

    button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("copy svg with setImage")
    button2.pressed.connect(button_pressed_svg_set_image)

    button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("copy png with setData")
    button3.pressed.connect(button_pressed_png_set_data)

    button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("copy svg with setData")
    button4.pressed.connect(button_pressed_svg_set_data)

    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(button)
    layout.addWidget(button2)
    layout.addWidget(button3)
    layout.addWidget(button4)

    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(layout)
    window.setCentralWidget(widget)

    window.show()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. You say that you want to copy raster *OR* vector data, and in the last code you're setting the data as vector, but you say that you use that code for raster images. Can you please clarify? Also, not all programs are able to get svg contents from the clipboard, but some of them are by using "paste special" functions, usually in the "Edit" or context menus.

Comment: Hey, I just switched the type in the second example to "svg" to indicate how I would handle a "svg" image...   (for png it would be  `savefig(format="png")` and then `data.setData("image/png", ...)`   the strange thing is that now neither the svg nor the png is recognized by apps that were perfectly capable of pasting images with the first script (e.g. using `setImage(...)`)

Comment: Assuming that a proper and valid svg format is correctly stored in the buffer, the codes above should work as expected: using `setImage()` as much as `data.setData()` with the proper mime type. So, either there is a bug in `savefig()`, or you're using a different code (a [mre] would really help here), or there is some problem with your OS; what OS do you use? do you have a clipboard manager? Did you try to restart the computer or, at least, the session?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comments! I added a minimal working example at the bottom of the question. Any help is highly appreciated!  (I'm on Windows 10 without a clipboard manager)

Comment: Which application are you pasting into?  @musicamante is quite right that some applications can only read some formats.

Comment: Well, for example paint, word or similar.  Pasting data copied with setImage works but not with setData ... My question is why?

Comment: @raphael on Linux it works as expected: using `setImage()` will copy a *raster* image to the clipboard (even if you're using the 'svg' format for `savefig()`, because you're passing through QImage). `setData()` copies the raster image when using the png, and an actual svg image in the other case. Are you saying that when copying the *png* image with `setMimeData()` you don't get the image not even in paint? Note that I'm not completely sure paint supports pasting svg content, and, as said, other non-primarily graphics programs such as word processors might need the mentioned "paste special".

Comment: @raphael Note that the `pyqtSlot()` decorator is almost never really necessary (the PyQt maintainer himself suggests to avoid them generally) and, in any case, it makes only sense if used for QObject subclasses: using it for generic functions is useless.

Comment: @musicamante thanks! ...and yes, for me, `setImage` works with paint but `setData` does not (both png and svg). Same is true for libre office writer, marktex and others. The only exception is inkscape where all works as expected.  (...also thx for the qtslot hint!)